# Angular Material - Prevent mat-stepper from navigating between steps

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-stepper

I have a `mat-horizontal-stepper` where I set linear property as true. When all the steps are valid as of now I can navigate to previous steps by clicking the header or label. I don't want that property.

I need to navigate only through buttons.

I tried disabling pointer function with:

```
    .mat-horizontal-stepper-header{
       pointer-events: none;
     }
```

but it didn't worked.

I need either to stop navigating by clicking header or fire a function on clicking the stepper header.

Answer (score 13):

What you originally posted:

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

does work, as long as you add `::ng-deep` to the CSS class. Like this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Also make sure you are using the *horizontal* stepper instead of the *vertical* one. This obviously matters when calling the appropriate CSS class.

Comment: Yeah, but your way can be easily countered by "inspect" tool and disabling css rule

Answer (score 12):

i had a similar issue as you had, and what i did was:

1. In html, I configured [editable] and [completed] as false

`<mat-step [completed]="false" [editable]="false">`

2. In the .ts file, corresponding action will trigger the following:

```
this.stepper.selected.completed = true;
this.stepper.next();
```

And of course, enabled linear mode.

Comment: How do you trigger the step 2.? What event do you use?

Comment: I have a button which will call function that will (along with other functions I need) trigger the following:

        this.stepper.selected.completed = true;
        this.stepper.next();

So this will jump to the subsequent step.

Answer (score 7):

To get event on header click use this-

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper (selectionChange)="stepClick($event)" [linear]="isLinear" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper">
```

In ts file the component -

```
stepClick(ev) {console.log(ev)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set editable to false for `mat-step`

```
<mat-step editable="false"> ... </mat-step>
```

Comment: It doesn't worked in this case when the previous values are valid

Answer (score 3):

To fire a function when clicking the stepper header, you can subscribe to `MatStepper.selectionChange`. It is emitted when switching steps and gives you information about the previous step and the selected step.

html:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper[linear]="true">
  <mat-step label="firstStep">
    ...
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

ts:

```
class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stepper.selectionChange.subscribe(selection => {
       console.log(selection.selectedStep)
       console.log(selection.previouslySelectedStep)
    }
 }
```

When the selected step is the last one, you could use this to set `editable = false` in all the previous steps:

```
this.stepper._steps.forEach(step => step.editable = false);
```

Comment: thanks for this - If anyone else experiences an error that says the stepper is 'undefined', you can also subscribe in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 1):

I tried this but not worked.

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
        pointer-events: none !important;
    }
```

Then i tried this.

```
.mat-step-header {
            pointer-events: none !important;
        }
```

This worked absolutely fine .

Thank You

Comment: Yeah, but your way can be easily countered by "inspect" tool and disabling css rule

Answer (score -1):

`.mat-stepper-horizontal {
  pointer-events: none;
}`